# How to pass arguments in execute command? php laravel telegram bot

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

I tried execute commands with arguments in getUpdates block code:

```
public function getUpdates() {

    $commandsHandler = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);

    if(stripos($telegram['text'], 'REF') !== false) {

        $arguments = array(
            'ID' => $telegram['text']
        );

        Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute('partner', $arguments, $commandsHandler);

        die();
    }
```

but if i pass arguments, execute not working, without arguments all ok, what problem? How i can pass arguments to execute command?

Comment: There seem to be several projects named "Telegram" -- it might help folks answer your question better if you could link to which project you're using, or if you don't know that, how you installed telegram.

Comment: i use https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Comment: You mention in your question that "execute not working", but you don't describe what "not working means".  Do you see an error?  Does it just "not work", and if so, what would "working" mean to you?

Comment: execute just does not work, without error

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  It's not clear from your post what's supposed to happen when you call the `execute` method.  That context can be very important when you're trying to get someone to help solve your problem.

Comment: you need command handler code?

Comment: for example: $this->replyWithMessage(['text'=>"test"]); , it's return message "test" in telegram, if i use arguments, message not returned

Comment: I think it's not so important